# Minimum number of moves to reach a point in a grid?

Tags: algorithm, coordinate-systems

Starting from (0, 0) , I have to reach (x, y) in such a way that at any point I can move one step left/right if previous move was up/down and vice-versa. What is the minimum number of moves needed ?

Comment: It's approximately 2*max(x,y), give or take at most 2. But I'm not sure if Stack Overflow is the right place for this question. SO could be the right place if you had written an algorithm, and there's something wrong with it.

Comment: What do you mean by zigzags here ?

Comment: @Dialecticus, there has to be an exact answer.

Comment: obviously `x + y` steps are necessary minimum.

Comment: @holex only if abs(x-y) <= 1. If not then you need more.

Comment: @Dialecticus, why would you need more? the shortest way reaching the `(1, 10)` from `(0, 0)`  is exactly `11` steps you cannot reach it via shorter way than this and we don't need more (however we can walk around freely before). the `abs(1-10) = 9`, so your theory looks broken to me.

Comment: @holex, no it is wrong. For answer to be 11, the path taken is move up and then take all steps right and the alternate. But it is not adhering to the constraints given.

Comment: @user155768, oh, I see now, you need an alternate path not a straight one. you are right, in that case my suggestion is not correct at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the statement as every *left-right* movement must be followed an *up-down* move, and visa-versa, the following formula can give you the length of the shortest path.

let us assume the `x` and `y` are positive distances what we need to walk in both direction, so

> *x, y ∈ ℕ<sup>+</sup> ⋃ {0}*

then

> *steps = min (x, y) × 2 + 4 × floor (abs (x - y) / 2) + (x + y) mod 2*

where the

- *min (a, b)* gives the smaller value of `a` and `b`, like *min (1, 2) = 1*;
- *floor (x)* gives the whole part of `x` without fraction part, like *floor(4.5) = 4*;
- *abs(x)* gives the positive distance of `x` from zero, like *abs(-3) = abs(3) = 3*;
- *x mod y* gives the modulus (or remainder) of `x / y`, like *11 / 2 = 5 with remainder of 1*;

example:

- in the case of `(0, 10)` the *steps* are `20`;
- in the case of `(1, 10)` the *steps* are `19`;
- in the case of `(8, 5)` the *steps* are `15`;
- in the case of `(3, 3)` the *steps* are `6`;

etc...

Comment: I assume the `x` an `y` are always equal or greater than zero. that is what I inveted the formula with. if any of those can negative you need to take the `abs(...)` of that number, before you use the formula.

Comment: @user, please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to notice: the order of the moves is not significant (up, up, left is equivalent to up, left, up).
So the constraint become `number of horizontal moves = number of vertical moves ± 1`.

You have to move to `(x, y)` (`x + y` moves) and then move along the x axis (assuming `x < y`) so that `number of horizontal moves = number of vertical moves ± 1`.

Hence the answer is `x + y + 2*k` such that `x + 2*k = y` or `x + 2*k = y - 1`.

Comment: I've tried to understand your answer (for learning purpose only), and it is not quite clear to me where the `k` comes from... it looks to me as an undefined and unknown value. what is that actually?